# How to return the whole object data with Django objects.filter?

Tags: python, django

I search for a user in my views:

```
user = User.objects.filter(id=id).first()
print(user)
```

This returns just the username of the user. I know I can access other data like the `nickname` with `user.nickname` but I need to make a json object of the user data and would like to know is there some way I can access the whole user object at once and not one by one?

Comment: When you call `print(user)`, you call `__str__` method of the model. Try overwriting the method to return all fields as JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to convert an instance to a dictionary.

---

### 1. `instance.__dict__`

```
instance.__dict__
```

which returns

```
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7fa91aacd850>, 'id': 1, 'password': 'pbkdf2_sha256$260000$EXJTbB1QbxdxNMyPeKiixS$ghD+e5KTTvUwGdoXWr02ocjq+1t7/a277pBxxDncgWE=', 'last_login': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 10, 7, 5, 25, 542308, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'is_superuser': True, 'username': 'admin123', 'first_name': '', 'last_name': '', 'email': '', 'is_staff': True, 'is_active': True, 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 25, 14, 23, 38, 892836, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

This is the simplest, but is missing `many_to_many`, `foreign_key`.

---

### 2. `model_to_dict`

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
model_to_dict(instance)
```

which returns

```
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7fa91aacd850>, 'id': 1, 'password': 'pbkdf2_sha256$260000$EXJTbB1QbxdxNMyPeKiixS$ghD+e5KTTvUwGdoXWr02ocjq+1t7/a277pBxxDncgWE=', 'last_login': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 10, 7, 5, 25, 542308, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'is_superuser': True, 'username': 'admin123', 'first_name': '', 'last_name': '', 'email': '', 'is_staff': True, 'is_active': True, 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 25, 14, 23, 38, 892836, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

---

### 3. `model_to_dict(instance, fields=instance_fields)`

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
model_to_dict(instance, fields=[field.name for field in instance._meta.fields])
```

which returns

```
{'id': 1, 'password': 'pbkdf2_sha256$260000$EXJTbB1QbxdxNMyPeKiixS$ghD+e5KTTvUwGdoXWr02ocjq+1t7/a277pBxxDncgWE=', 'last_login': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 10, 7, 5, 25, 542308, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'is_superuser': True, 'username': 'admin123', 'first_name': '', 'last_name': '', 'email': '', 'is_staff': True, 'is_active': True, 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 25, 14, 23, 38, 892836, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

This is strictly worse than the standard `model_to_dict` invocation.

---

### 4. Use Serializers

[Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)'s ModelSerialzer allows you to build a serializer automatically from a model.

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = SomeModel
         fields = "__all__"

SomeModelSerializer(instance).data
```

which returns

```
{'field1': 'value1', 'field1': 'value2'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `user.__dict__` to get the dictionary of the object. If you want to get multiple object's data in dictionary format, consider using [Values Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#values):

```
data = User.objects.values('nickname')
print(json.dumps(list(data)))
```